# How to get User Assigned to from task list

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, event-handlers

An event handler that counts how many workflow tasks the ‘assigned to’ person/group has been assigned with?

Across multiple task lists.

It is assigned to a SharePoint group - it’s not assigned to an individual user. So I have to be able to count how many tasks that group is assigned

Comment: Why not use a search Result web part , looking for content type "workflow Task" and assigned to "the group" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use search API:

```
var selectedParameter='&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=%27500%27&selectproperties=%27Title,Path%27';
var searchApi=_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+ '/_api/search/query?querytext=%27ContentType:"Tasks CT" AND AssignedToOWSCHCS:"Value"+' %27'+selectedParameter
```